# Possible to auto height child div? (not 100% of parent)

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to simply auto-height a child div to the remaining height not being used by other component of it's parent? For the below example, the .body would only be like 20px high, because it's only using that much for the inner html. Is it possible for the .body to automatically consume the unused height of the .parent? e.g. .parent 200px - .head 30px - .foot 30px = .body 120px?

The sample below will display the .parent yellow box much taller than the used space. If you set .body to "height: 100%", it'll use the parent's height and not respect the .head or .foot elements.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.head { height: 30px; background-color: blue; }

.body { background-color: #999; }

.foot { height: 30px; background-color: green; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="head">I'm the head</div>
  <div class="body">I'm the body</div>
  <div class="foot">I'm the foot</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is only an example. In my project the .parent height can only be reasonably set in the .parent element. Plus the .parent height is essentially dynamically set by the back-end code. The three inner div organization is because the body is collapsible and I have rounded corners for the head and foot.

Any suggestions are well appreciated!

Comment: Yes I do. The body needs to scale with the height of the parent. The parent will be assigned a class that will take care of the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be achieved with negative margins!

1. Set `.body` to 100% height
2. Assuming that the height of `.head` and `.foot` is known, you can add a negative top + bottom margin equal to the respective heights of `.head` and `.foot`.
3. Because of the source ordering, the `.body` will "cover" `.head`. To counter this, add `position: relative` to `.head`.
4. The inner content of the body need to be shifted down a bit. You cannot add padding to `.body` directly. Better, add another dive inside `.body` with padding top + bottom set to desired height.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/SRXqC/)

Variant of the above example:

1. Set `.body` to 100% height
2. Assuming that the height of `.head` and `.foot` is known, you can add a negative bottom margin equal to the sum of heights of `.head` and `.foot`.
3. Since `.body` will attempt to flow outside the parent, add `overflow: hidden` to the parent.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/SRXqC/1/)

Comment: The only thing wrong with negative margins is it doesn't affect borders. If you add a border to a div with a 100% height + a negative margin you end up with the height being what you'd expect, but the borders will continue the full height of the parent. Also in the demo the margin-top makes the body pop up behind the head. (the body text is behind the head) It should be margin-bottom: -30px only. (maybe this is a browser difference)

Comment: If you add a 2px top+bottom border to a 100% tall element, the height it _occupies_ is 100% + 4px. You probably need to include the border sizes in the margins. As for the second issue, look at note #4; or the second demo which works around that problem.

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment above in time. It doesn't work in the demo because the body top 30px is hidden behind the header. The margin-top: -30px; is clipping the top. If you switch to a margin-bottom: -60px, the height is correct but you'll notice that the displayed background is doesn't stop at the parent's height. e.g. it's 30px too long. Even with .body overflow: hidden;, the negative margin isn't respected and the background-color is still displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/SRXqC/2/

Comment: Race condition comments! You're right, the 2nd demo is correct for my sample. Borders are still a problem, but weren't in my original question. Maybe you have a suggestion for this. When rounding corners, the body borders will continue and the negative margin won't affect them. See my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/SRXqC/3/

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two ways to achieve this. Both are somewhat unsatisfactory.

The first is to calculate the remaining height using DOM information via JS.

The second is called CSS3 flexbox and works perfectly, but is an immature specification with currently very little [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Unfortunately this can't be done using CSS 2.1 and that's one of the reasons why CSS sucks so badly.

Comment: Agreed, Interesting how often flexbox offers a solution to common CSS problems, yet how little support it has.

Comment: @mikevoermans It's a complicated spec that evolved out of Mozilla's XUL flexible boxes. Both Mozilla and Webkit are actively working on their respective implementations of the updated version of the spec right now, others maybe too.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I wanted to avoid using JS, but I think we already acknowledge that's an ugly approach.